# SSL for Encrypting Voice data

Tags: java, android, ssl, encryption

For some course project, I would like to implement encryption for voice. I'm using Java mainly. I have some few questions:

- Do you recommend me to use an SSL or just Java library like "BouncyCastle" will suffice. Notice, since this is a course project, maybe it's better to be a bit sophisticated and use SSL, unless that is really doesn't make sense.
- Is there any example of using SSL to encrypt voice.
- I guess implementing SSL by myself is beyond the scope of course project. Do you agree? if so do you recommend any open source library in Java.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you question is ok, but asking for a product recommendation is not okay here because of obvious reasons. But it would be okay on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com , I would suggest to re-ask your question there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Do you recommend me to use an SSL or just Java library like "BouncyCastle" will suffice.

It will suffice, but using an SSL socket is easier.

> Notice, since this is a course project, maybe it's better to be a bit sophisticated and use SSL, unless that is really doesn't make sense.

Your call.

> - Is there any example of using SSL to encrypt voice.

It's no different from sending anything else. You have bytes, you send them.

> I guess implementing SSL by myself is beyond the scope of course project.

What coures project?

> Do you agree?

There's nothing here to agree with. It's your course and your project. How would we know?

> if so do you recommend any open source library in Java.

Why? SSL and encryption are both built-in.